# First chart created in a loop is different from subsequent charts

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts

I have a loop that produces the charts automatically from a set of data. My issue is that the first chart is always different from the subsequent charts.Can anyone help with why my first chart is always different than my subsequent charts?

Here is what the charts look like after i run the code:

[image: Charts]

Here is my code:

```
Sub Pyramid()

 Sheets("Pyramid").Select
 Range("C2").Select
 ActiveCell.Range("B1:J1").Select


    For counter = 2 To 5
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1Pyramid.crtx")
        With ActiveChart
             Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
                .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
             Loop
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("'Pyramid'!$W$2" & ":$AN$2") 'BC males
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("'Pyramid'!$W$3" & ":$AN$3") 'BC females
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("'Pyramid'!$C$" & counter & ":$K$" & counter) 'Community males
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("'Pyramid'!$M$" & counter & ":$U$" & counter) 'Community females
                .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Pyramid'!$V$2" 'BC males
                .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "='Pyramid'!$V$3" 'BC females
                .FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "='Pyramid'!$B$2" 'Community males
                .FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "='Pyramid'!$L$2" 'Community females
        End With

        ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts"

        With ActiveChart
            .HasTitle = False
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = -15
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 15
            .FullSeriesCollection(3).Select
                With Selection.Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .Patterned msoPatternLightVertical
                End With
                Selection.AxisGroup = 2
            .FullSeriesCollection(4).Select
                With Selection.Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .Patterned msoPatternLightVertical
                End With
                Selection.AxisGroup = 2
            .Parent.Top = 50
            .Parent.Left = c * 130
        End With
        Sheets("Charts").Select

        c = c + 3
    Next counter
Range("J1").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue over here.